# Complex MapReduce configuration scenario

Tags: java, configuration, hadoop, mapreduce

Consider an application that wants to use `Hadoop` in order to process large amounts of proprietary binary-encoded text data in approximately the following simplified `MapReduce` sequence:

1. Gets a URL to a file or a directory as input
2. Reads the list of the binary files found under the input URL
3. Extracts the text data from each of those files
4. Saves the text data into new, extracted plain text files
5. Classifies extracted files into (sub)formats of special characteristics (say, "context")
6. Splits each of the extracted text files according to its context, if necessary
7. Processes each of the splits using the context of the original (unsplit) file
8. Submits the processing results to a proprietary data repository

The format-specific characteristics (context) identified in Step 5 are also saved in a (small) text file as key-value pairs, so that they are accessible by Step 6 and Step 7.

Splitting in Step 6 takes place using custom `InputFormat` classes (one per custom file format).

In order to implement this scenario in Hadoop, one could integrate Step 1 - Step 5 in a `Mapper` and use another `Mapper` for Step 7.

A problem with this approach is how to make a custom `InputFormat` know which extracted files to use in order to produce the splits. For example, format A may represent 2 extracted files with slightly different characteristics (e.g., different line delimiter), hence 2 different contexts, saved in 2 different files.

Based on the above, the `getSplits(JobConf)` method of each custom `InputFormat` needs to have access to the context of each file before splitting it. However, there can be (at most) 1 `InputFormat` class per format, so **how would one correlate the appropriate set of extracted files with the correct context file?**

A solution could be to use some specific naming convention for associating extracted files and contexts (or vice versa), but is there any better way?

Answer (score 0):

This sounds more like a Storm (stream processing) problem with a spout that loads the list of binary files from a URL and subsequent bolts in the topology performing each of the following actions.